# Trouble converting string to uniqueidentifier for SSRS subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, database-administration

We have a DBA who left the company.  That DBA created a bunch of SSRS subscriptions and when their Active Directory account was turned off, all the subscriptions failed.  I am working with IT to create a generic active directory account to use to manage all the subscriptions so this will not happen again.  However, there is some political stuff going on, so in the meantime I need to change who these subscriptions belong to so reports can keep generating.  I am running this code:

```
 DECLARE @OldUserID uniqueidentifier
 DECLARE @NewUserID uniqueidentifier
 SELECT @OldUserID = CAST( UserID as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserID ='Domain\First.Last'
 SELECT  @NewUserID= CAST( UserID as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = 'Domain\NewFirst.NewLast'
 UPDATE dbo.Subscriptions SET OwnerID = @NewUserID WHERE OwnerID = @OldUserID
```

Except I get the error

> “Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 8 Conversion failed when converting
>   from a character string to uniqueidentifier.”

So I took out the single quotes and tried this:

```
DECLARE @OldUserID uniqueidentifier
 DECLARE @NewUserID uniqueidentifier
 SELECT @OldUserID = CAST( UserID as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserID = Domain\First.Last
 SELECT  @NewUserID= CAST( UserID as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = Domain\NewFirst.NewLast
 UPDATE dbo.Subscriptions SET OwnerID = @NewUserID WHERE OwnerID = @OldUserID
```

And I got the error:

> “Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect
>
> > syntax near '\'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax
> >     near '\'.”

When I google my issue, I can’t seem to find an answer so I think this is something very simple that I am missing.  I would appreciate any help so I can get these subscriptions back up and running.

Comment: I think the problem is in the first query.  You're saying `WHERE UserID = 'Domain\...'`. I think you meant `WHERE UserName = 'Domain\...'`

Comment: Siyual, you are brilliant.  I knew it was something stupid I was missing.  You are totally right!  I just needed another set of eyes.  Thank you!